# How to fix "error : file not found: (file name) Usage: javac <options> <source files>" on Linux?

Tags: javascript, java, linux, visual-studio-code

Good evening, all. I am currently completing an assignment for my introductory compsci course and I'm trying to run a basic HelloWorld program. However, when typing "javac HelloWorld.java", the message "error: file not found: HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac  
use --help for a list of possible options"
keeps popping up. I've scoured the internet and have no idea how to fix this issue using my Linux terminal inside visual studio code. I've saved the file, have opened and reopened it countless times but to no avail. Please, I beg, help me if you have any idea for me to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you have a `HelloWorld.java` file in the current directory?

Comment: Enter `ls -lha` and see whether the file is in the current folder. Also use `pwd` to see the current directory path you are in. Then `cd path/to/dir/where/your/java/file/locates`

Comment: When I use ls -lha I see one HelloWorld file, highlighted in light blue.

Comment: Is the file called `HelloWorld` or `HelloWorld.java`?

Comment: It's called HelloWorld.java, but when I send ls -lha, HelloWorld in bright blue letters shows up.

Comment: Is it a directory?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just doubled checked and I have my HelloWorld.java file in my current directory.

Comment: can you post the screenshot about error and folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

@Brandon, Just a note, the mentioned error (by you) occurs only if there is no expected file to compile in the specified location.

If `HelloWorld` is highlighted in light blue on issuing `ls -lha` means it may be a *directory* and might not be a *file*. Can you please double check it as mentioned below?

Are you able to navigate into the `HelloWorld` *directory* by using the following command: `cd HelloWorld`? If it is, please check what are the files available inside the *directory* by issuing `ls -lha`. Then it might help to proceed further.